# Give permission to a user and profile to edit visual force page and apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, permissions

As a admin I have created one custom visual force page and apex class.

How can I give permission to a profile to edit that visual force page and apex class?

My 2nd requirement is that only one user has the rights to edit that visual force page and apex class.

How can I give permission for only one user?

Comment: Use permission set and provide Author Apex permission and assign that permission set to user whom you want to extend the access for Apex Class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot give permissions to edit just *one* class or page. It is all or none at that level. The permission required is `Author Apex` and will allow any user who has this permission all classes and pages (and other things).

As for which users to assign it to, however, you *can* assign to just one user, but `Profile` is not the way to do it. You would instead use `Permission Sets`. First add the desired permission, then assign the desired user to it.

Comment: Thanks Nachiket and Adrian for your response.Through Author Apex in Permission set for a particular user , that user is able to edit all apex classes but still not able to edit and view visual force page. Is there any property which I have to enable for editing and viewing visual force page for a particular user.

Comment: @Raam If one of these answers [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a permission set and assign it to user whom you want to extend the access. Permission sets are used for extending the access without modifying the permission of user profile.

> **Permission Sets**
>  A permission set is a collection of settings and permissions that give users access to various tools and functions.
>   The settings and permissions in permission sets are also found in
>   profiles, but permission sets extend users' functional access without
>   changing their profiles.
>
> **Author Apex**
>
> Can modify and deploy Apex classes and triggers, set security on Apex
>   classes, and create email services